# How to check if all divs have a specific background-color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've dynamically added a bunch of divs of a certain class to my page, and they change color when the user hovers over them. I want to trigger a specific function when the last one has been set to a specific background color, but after messing around for some time I am still unsuccessful. If anyone could provide some insight, I would be very appreciative. The code below is from my latest attempt.

```
var counter=0;
$(".orb").each(function () {
    if ($(this).css("background-color") === "#ede74a") {
        counter=counter+1;
    }
}
if (counter === orbarray.length) { //all backgrounds have been set
    executeFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear from the code you've provided what `orbarray` equals. It's also odd that you're checking to see if `counter` equals the length of that array *outside* of the `$.each()` callback.

But so you're saying you need to trigger a specific function when the last `<div>` has been hovered over. Sounds like you want a handler for the `mouseenter` event, and to then check whether *all* the elements have been hovered over in that handler. Also, instead of applying inline CSS, if you apply a class you'll have a handier way to check whether the element has been hovered.

Observe:

```
function checkOrbs() {
  var $orbs = $('.orb'),
      $activeOrbs = $orbs.filter('.active');

  if ($orbs.length === $activeOrbs.length) {
    executeFunction();
  }
}

$('.orb').on('mouseenter', function(e) {
  var $target = $(e.target);

  $target.addClass('active');

  checkOrbs();
});
```

And then just apply your background color via CSS:

```
.active {
  background-color: #ede74a;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the example

Answer (score 2):

Would be simpler to add a class to the elements and keep track of class

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.orb',function(){ 
    var $orb = $(".orb"); 
    $(this).addClass('hovered');
    if($orb.filter('.hovered').length === $orb.length){
       alert('All hovered!');
       executeFunction();
    }
});
```

It's not clear exactly what is happening with the specific colors mentioned but this could be adapted for multiple classes if need be.

Note that browsers don't store colors as hex values....they store them as either `rgb` or `rgba` depending on browser

Comment: If poster is dynamically adding ```.orb``` elements, it may not be safe to store them in a variable ahead of time, as opposed to checking them within the handlers.

Comment: @benjarwar yep...I didn't notice the dynamically added part